# AnyLogic PLE v8.76 quit unexpectedly when launching on mac

Tags: macos, exit, anylogic

I use AnyLogic PLE v8.76 on mac. It worked fine for a week, but today I got problem launching the software. I keep getting this message:
[image]

And this is the error shown:

[image]

I tried to download Anylogic again, but I still got the same problem...
I did not download any other softwares or change things on my mac.
Can somebody help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Please add the exact version of AnyLogic that you are using e.g. AnyLogic PLE v8.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option, as often advised by the AnyLogic support team, is to clear the workspace.

Try the following:

1. Make hidden files and folders visible on your Mac - cmd+shit+.
2. Navigate to your user folder (Either from he side bar, or Macintosh HD -> Users->(yourname)
3. Find the `.AnyLogic...` folder, on mine it is called `.AnyLogicProffesional`
4. Delete the following two folders `workspace8.x` and `configuiration8.x` where the 8.x indicates your version number of the currently installed AnyLogic version.

These files keep settings and the currently loaded models on the disk and will remain even if you download a new version of AnyLogic, which is why downloading a new version does not always solve these kinds of problems.

If the issue still persists contact support, they might ask you to send the error report you got from your Mac (so copy and paste it to a document the next time you get it) as well as some error logs that get stored in these hidden files and folders. (Now you at least know where to find them ;-) )

If my solution did not provide the answer, please add an answer if you manage to find it.